# How can I use an if statement within or outside of a switch statement (C++)

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

I am brand new to programming and am doing coding challenges found from here http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/. I cannot find the answer to my specific question through google searches, this is my first time posting here so I apologize if I've broken any guidelines! I am looking at the challenge which makes a user pick a number to select their favorite beverage.

I just learned about the switch statement and i named 5 cases, not including the default. I was trying to figure out how to incorporate an if statement inside of a switch statement (if this is even possible), or maybe it's a for loop that i am looking for? I am not sure but i'm willing to learn about whatever it is. I am trying to make it so that if the user does not enter a valid case number and it goes to default. (ex: anything other than 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5) I want the user to make another attempt at entering a correct number when it hits the default case.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "Choose your beverage of choice by number: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Coke" << endl;
    cout << "2. Dr. Pepper" << endl;
    cout << "3. Sprite" << endl;
    cout << "4. Iced Tea" << endl;
    cout << "5. Water" << endl;
    cout << '\n';
    cin >> choice;
    cout << '\n' << "Choice entered: " << choice << endl;
    cout << '\n';
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1 : cout << "You have chosen Coke." << endl;
        break;
        case 2 : cout << "You have chosen Dr. Pepper." << endl;
        break;
        case 3 : cout << "You have chosen Sprite." << endl;
        break;
        case 4 : cout << "You have chosen Iced Tea." << endl;
        break;
        case 5: cout << "You have chosen Water." << endl;
        break;
        default: 
        cout << "Error. Choice Not valid. Money returned." << endl;
        break;

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to make it so that if the user does not enter a valid case number and it goes to default. (ex: anything other than 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5) I want the user to make another attempt at entering a correct number when it hits the default case.

One way to make this happen is to put a `do-while` loop around the block of code that receives user input and the `switch` statement.

```
int main()
{
   bool isValidChoice = true;
   do
   {
      // Reset when the loop is run more than once.
      isValidChoice = true;

      int choice;

      cout << "Choose your beverage of choice by number: " << endl;
      cout << "1. Coke" << endl;
      cout << "2. Dr. Pepper" << endl;
      cout << "3. Sprite" << endl;
      cout << "4. Iced Tea" << endl;
      cout << "5. Water" << endl;
      cout << '\n';
      cin >> choice;
      cout << '\n' << "Choice entered: " << choice << endl;
      cout << '\n';
      switch (choice)
      {
         case 1 :
            cout << "You have chosen Coke." << endl;
            break;

         case 2 :
            cout << "You have chosen Dr. Pepper." << endl;
            break;

         case 3 :
            cout << "You have chosen Sprite." << endl;
            break;

         case 4 :
            cout << "You have chosen Iced Tea." << endl;
            break;

         case 5:
            cout << "You have chosen Water." << endl;
            break;

         default: 
            cout << "Error. Choice Not valid. Money returned." << endl;
            isValidChoice = false;
            break;
      }
   } while ( !isValidChoice );
}
```

Comment: This worked when i did it in the order you have it! I wanted to change the statement that says 'money returned' to 'enter a valid choice'. If i try to put  
bool isValidChoice = true;
   do
   {

in front of the switch statement instead of it enclosing everything, it will not run. Do you know why?

Comment: If you do that, you are not including the code to receive input again from the user after an invalid choice is entered.